# Standard normal tail approximation (A question from Pitman's book)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading Pitman's book "Probability" and I don't know how to solve [17.c](http://www.technion.ac.il/~nickc/Normal-Approx-Ex.pdf)
 (last question in the pdf).

I thought of integration by parts but that didn't really work for me..the book does not have a final answer for this question...

Comment: Substitute $u={-1\over2} x^2$.

Comment: This is a duplicate (of a duplicate of a duplicate...). See the `faq` tag or the related topic on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to (or will) show that
$$
\int_z^\infty {x\over z} {1\over \sqrt{2\pi} }e^{-x^2/2}\,dx={\phi(z)\over z},
$$
where $\phi(z)={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}$.

Hint:

Let $u={x^2\over 2}$. Then $du=x\,dx$, when $x=z$, $u=z^2/2$, and when $x=\infty$, $u= \infty$.

Solution:

Substitution then gives
$$
\int_z^\infty {x\over z} {1\over \sqrt{2\pi} }e^{-x^2/2}\,dx
=\int_{z^2/2}^{\infty}{1\over z\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u}\,du
={-1\over z\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u}\Biggl|_{z^2/2}^\infty ={e^{-z^2/2}\over z\sqrt{2\pi}}={\phi(z)\over z}. 
$$