# Boundary for Gaussian normal variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be i. i. d.
For every $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n \}$ $X_k \overset{\strut\text{d}}= N(0, 1)$ .

I am to check whether
$$\mid X_n \mid \le \sqrt{2 \log n},$$
for almost all $n$ .

I think that the statement above is false. However I don't know how to prove it. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to know one useful approximation: for large $x>0$, $$P(|X_n|\gt x)=2P(X_n\gt x)\approx\frac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{x}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}.$$Thus$$P(|X_n|\gt\sqrt{2\ln n})\approx\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\pi\ln n}}.$$The question is whether there are almost surely only finitely many satisfactions of this inequality, i.e. whether the number of such instances is almost surely finite. Indeed, to within a finite additive constant, the mean number of "big" $X_n$ approximates $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\pi\ln n}}.$$To finish, we just use the integral test: $$\int_e^\infty\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln x}}=\int_1^\infty\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}=\infty.$$

Comment: So that means that this inequality does not hold? That's a nice solution, thanks. Can you add some reference when I can check out the approximation you've mentioned?

Comment: @Hendrra See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131381/standard-normal-tail-approximation-a-question-from-pitmans-book).